# Call WCF REST Service from .NETCF 2.0 Smart Device Application

Tags: wcf, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I need to Call WCF REST Service from .NETCF 2.0 Smart Device Application. There us no "Add Service Reference" option for adding reference to WCF service in .NETCF 2.0 Smart Device Application.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at using [something like RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) unless it's just a few calls, in which case just rolling your won HttpWebRequest implementation is pretty easy.

Comment: How to post JSON in HttpWebRequest to WCF REST Service?

Comment: Package your data in JSON (it's pretty simple and there are parsers available) and send it as the payload in a POST.